# Form::open get the wrong route if the page is called by Redirect::back

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

On my route.php I have

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Artisan route command gives me

```
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                         | Name          | Action                 | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                  |               | Closure                |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users              | users.index   | UserController@index   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/create       | users.create  | UserController@create  |                |               |
|        | POST users                  | users.store   | UserController@store   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}      | users.show    | UserController@show    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}/edit | users.edit    | UserController@edit    |                |               |
|        | PUT users/{users}           | users.update  | UserController@update  |                |               |
|        | PATCH users/{users}         |               | UserController@update  |                |               |
|        | DELETE users/{users}        | users.destroy | UserController@destroy |                |               |
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Then I have a page for editing users with 2 forms, the first one for editing, the second one for deleting:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put')) }}
...
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
```

Finally into the UserController I use a validation that redirect to the previous page in case of unsuccesful validation:

```
if (!$this->user->isValid($id))
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->user->errors);
}
```

When I land on the edit page from the the users list page, the HTML for both forms looks fine (note the hidden _method field with value DELETE):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.virtualbox.me/users/8" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
...
<form method="POST" action="http://www.virtualbox.me/users/8" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
```

But if I insert a value on a field that cause the validation to fail, then on the reloaded page also the second form get method PUT instead of DELETE:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.virtualbox.me/users/8" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
...
<form method="POST" action="http://www.virtualbox.me/users/8" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work.... change this line to:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::except('_method'))->withErrors($this->user->errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Laravel automatically change your method behind the scene it is mentioned as a note in [Docs.](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form) As browsers don't understand PUT, PATCH, DELETE requests.

So you need to add the _method field explicitly in your DELETE form.

```
<field type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```